# Bulking up in a 2 month time span

Tags: bodybuilding

This will be my first post on Fitness Stackexchange but I am very familiar with this great website (you may remember me from the Mathematics forums).

Well, I have 2 months before I leave for my home country of Italy (I am currently in the US) and would love to bulk. I have never bulked before but I have always been working out and weight lifting and doing the standard Chest-Tri, Back-Bi etc routine. I try to eat a lot but I have *always* been ~ 135 lbs. I am very "fit" and have worked out for *years* and get stronger but I do not see any real size.

Stats:

~ 135 lbs 
5'8"
slim/ectomorph

I do not have enough reputation to upload some pictures but I would if I could :P

So my question is this:

What am I doing wrong? Not eating enough? Too much basketball? I do not take whey or mass gainers as they contain lots of sucralose and artificial flavoring but I am open to the idea if anyone can provide mass gainers without artificial stuff. What exercises should I be doing?
Lastly, is it possible to bulk for 2 months? Or is that a long time?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Welcome! I voted to close as a duplicate because I believe the linked question should answer your question. If not, please add something distinguishing about your situation, and we should be able to help you!

Comment: Without very specific details on diet, exercise, sleep, and stress, I agree that this is a duplicate. "Eat more, squat and chin, sleep" is the general advice; for specific advice we need specific background.